# Cambiar el color de fondo de un mensaje alertify

Tags: alertify

Tengo el siguiente inconveniente, no se como cambiar el color de fondo del mensaje que aparece creado con alertify. He probado con la propiedad background-color = "#4546" y solo me cambia el color de texto en el cuerpo del mensaje. adjunto código del mensaje que se activa con una función. Desde ya gracias

```
 function prodexis(){
    var pre = document.createElement('pre');
    //custom style.
    pre.style.maxHeight = "600px";
    //pre.style.Width = "500px";
    pre.style.margin = "0";
    pre.style.padding = "18px";
    pre.style.whiteSpace = "";
    pre.style.textAlign = "justify";
    pre.style.color =  "black";

    pre.appendChild(document.createTextNode($('#exi').text()));
    //show as confirm
    alertify.alert(pre, function(){
        alertify.success('Mensaje cerrado');
    },).set({title:"Atención, lea  atentamente por favor "}).set({labels:{ok:'Accept', }, padding: false});
}
```

Agrego el div que contiene el mensaje:

```
<div id="exi" style ="display: none; font-size: 30px;">

Los productos que se observan con este color corresponde a 
productos recibidos en su totalidad por el proveedor, 
de acuerdo a la cantidad contratada.

   
Muchas Gracias.    
</div>
```

Comment: Depende del contexto del mensaje, prueba con alertify.info, o .warning

Comment: Lo que necesito es cambiar la propiedad background-color a un color especifico, pero no se donde colocarlo

Answer (score 0):

Tendras que añadir las clases css de alertify y sobre escribirlas, tendrás que usar el atributo `!important` para sobreescribir los estilos que trae por defecto, el resultado seria algo como:

```js
this.mensaje = () => {
alertify.alert("Exito", "facturacion registrado exitosamente", function () {});

alertify.success("succes");

alertify.error("error");
}
```

```css
.ajs-dialog{
    background: #36c060 !important;
  /*verde para el body*/
}
.ajs-header{
    background: #1b1485 !important;
  /*azul para el header*/
}
.ajs-footer{
    background: #fd3e0f !important;
  /*rojo para el footer*/
}

.ajs-success {
  background: #fd3e0f !important;
}

.ajs-success {
  background: #fd3e0f !important;
}

.ajs-error{
  background: #1b1485 !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/AlertifyJS/1.13.1/css/alertify.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/AlertifyJS/1.13.1/alertify.min.js"></script>


<input type="button" onclick="mensaje()" value="Mensaje"/>
```

Comment: Esto funciona bien amigo. Pero como deberia hacerse para modificar solo una alerta en particular y no todas. Porque al modificar por ejemplo .ajs-header. Me cambia los .ajs-header de todas las alertas y no una en particular

Comment: @JGuerreroS dependiendo del tipo de alerta que quieras usar se podra sobreescribir la clase css, añadi un ejemplo

Comment: El detalle es que por ejemplo un alertify.confirm y un alertify.alert. Ambas tienen un .ajs-header. Y si quisieras cambiar el color a las alertify.alert usando la clase .ajs-header. Pues el cambio de color también se hace a la alertify.confirm. Debido a que ambas tienen la clase .ajs-header. No se si me falta algo más, pero no veo una clase  que diferencie una de otra